# How to fix strange model accuracy graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to create a model that predicts'a' with 'b'.

I try to predict time-series data.
It consists of a total of 72 weeks of training set data and 32 weeks of verification data.

And my model consists of LSTM multilayers.

Show my python code

```
def train_lstm(x, y, train_size , epoch=500):
    time_step = x.shape[1]
    dim = x.shape[2]
    layer_size = 16

    x_data = x[:train_size]
    y_data = y[:train_size]
    x_val = x[train_size:]
    y_val = y[train_size:]

    K.clear_session()
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(layer_size, input_shape=(time_step, dim), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(layer_size, input_shape=(time_step, dim)))
    model.add(Dense(layer_size, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(layer_size, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam',  metrics=['accuracy'])
    record = model.fit(x_data,y_data,validation_data=(x_val,y_val), epochs=epoch, verbose=0)
    model.reset_states()

    #Print train log 1
    plt.title("loss graph")
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.plot(range(0,len(record.history['loss'])),record.history['loss'], '.-', color='black', label='train_loss')
    plt.plot(range(0,len(record.history['val_loss'])),record.history['val_loss'], '.-', color='blue', label='test_loss')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    plt.clf()

    #Print train log 2
    plt.title("acc graph")
    plt.ylabel('accuracy')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.plot(range(0,len(record.history['accuracy'])),record.history['accuracy'], '.-', color='black', label='train_loss')
    plt.plot(range(0,len(record.history['val_accuracy'])),record.history['val_accuracy'], '.-', color='blue', label='test_loss')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    plt.clf()
```

I succeed in predicting the value.
This graph shows that training loss decreased significantly as the number of training increases.

[loss graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6l8a.png) 
[acc graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orckO.png)

But the accurate rate graph is strange.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all flat and then, it starts jumping and then stops. Yes, this is weird. But, you don't have to worry about that, what you need is a smooth curve rising up. The first thing I would suggest you is to decrease your learning rate or set it (I can't see where you have set it up). Keep it at 3e-5, the golden learning rate. Then, play around with it. If that doesn't work reduce your layers in model and then, play with dropout. But, first try the learning rate.